# M1 Arm USB Passthrough with QEMU for Android Emulator

Tags: android-emulator, emulation, qemu, apple-m1, apple-silicon

**DESCRIBE THE ISSUE IN DETAIL:** Qemu USB passthrough on M1 with Mac OS Monteray using Android Emulator. From what I've gathered it's impossible due to the lack of libusb, but even after trying to add it manually, no luck. When trying to passthrough, I get 'usb-host' is not a valid device model name. This happens regardless of whether the device is plugged in or not.

**STEPS TO REPRODUCE:**

1. Create an Android Emulator on an M1 Mac
2. Open terminal window at emulator location
3. **Run** ./emulator -avd Pixel_C_API_Sv2 -qemu -device usb-host,bus=ehci.0,vendorid=0x045e,productid=0x0b00 and changed Pixel_C_API_SV2 to the name of you emulator.
4. Cry

**Terminal logs bellow:**

jonathankats@Jonathans-Macbook-Pro-2 emulator-2 % ./emulator -avd Pixel_C_API_Sv2 -qemu -device usb-host,bus=ehci.0,vendorid=0x045e,productid=0x0b00

INFO | Android emulator version 30.9.4.0 (build_id 7759208) (CL:N/A) WARNING | unexpected system image feature string, emulator might not function correctly, please try updating the emulator. WARNING | cannot add library /Users/jonathankats/Library/Android/sdk/emulator-2/qemu/darwin-aarch64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib: failed WARNING | cannot add library /Users/jonathankats/Library/Android/sdk/emulator-2/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib: failed WARNING | cannot add library /Users/jonathankats/Library/Android/sdk/emulator-2/qemu/darwin-aarch64/lib64/vulkan/libMoltenVK.dylib: failed INFO | added library /Users/jonathankats/Library/Android/sdk/emulator-2/lib64/vulkan/libMoltenVK.dylib createOrGetGlobalVkEmulation: warning: instance doesn't support external memory capabilities, picking first physical device INFO | configAndStartRenderer: setting vsync to 60 hz INFO | Sending adb public key [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 jonathankats@unknown] WARNING | Camera name 'webcam0' is not found in the list of connected cameras. Use '-webcam-list' emulator option to obtain the list of connected camera names.

INFO | Rootcanal has NOT been activated. INFO | Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local INFO | Advertising in: /Users/jonathankats/Library/Caches/TemporaryItems/avd/running/pid_7350.ini qemu-system-aarch64: -device usb-host,bus=ehci.0,vendorid=0x045e,productid=0x0b00: 'usb-host' is not a valid device model name WARNING | Unknown tab selected. libc++abi: terminating zsh: abort ./emulator -avd Pixel_C_API_Sv2 -qemu -device

**Studio Build:** Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 3 **Build** #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7784292, built on September 30, 2021 **Runtime version:** 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189 aarch64 **VM:** OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o. **Version of Java:** 14.0.1 **OS:** Mac OS Monteray 12.0